# why doesnt my github actions work, i tried to create a workflow?

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am building a react-native app, and i want ci in it.

At first i tried using circleci but after some talks i decided to try github actions.
I made a keystore, to deploy for android. I dont know if after making the keystore i should mention it somewhere. But something is going wrong in my github actions. I get this error message:

```
 Unexpected arguments: --no-publish, --release-channel=default, --auto-clean, --keystore-path=../../my-release-key.keystore, --keystore-alias=alias_name, --keystore-*** --key-*** --json-key=android, --env,
See more help with --help
    Error: build command failed.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

yml file and this is my code:

```
name: Build and Publish

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build-and-publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install EAS CLI
      run: npm install -g eas-cli

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: yarn install

    - name: Debug
      run: echo ${{ secrets.EXPO_USERNAME }} ${{ secrets.EXPO_PASSWORD }}

    - name: Install expect
      run: |
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get -y install expect

    - name: Expo login
      run: |
        export EAS_USERNAME="${{ secrets.EXPO_USERNAME }}"
        export EAS_PASSWORD="${{ secrets.EXPO_PASSWORD }}"
        expect -c '
          spawn eas login -u $env(EAS_USERNAME) -p $env(EAS_PASSWORD)
          expect {
            -exact "Email or username: " {
              send "$env(EAS_USERNAME)\r"
              exp_continue
            }
            -exact "Password: " {
              send "$env(EAS_PASSWORD)\r"
              exp_continue
            }
            eof
          }'
          
    - name: Install Expo CLI
      run: npm install -g expo-cli

    - name: Validate app.json
      run: expo config:validate

    - name: Build and Publish
      run: |
        eas build -p android \
          --no-publish \
          --release-channel=default \
          --auto-clean \
          --keystore-path=../../my-release-key.keystore \
          --keystore-alias=alias_name\
          --keystore-password=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD \
          --key-password=$KEY_PASSWORD \
          --json-key=android \
          --why=all \
          --env $(echo '${{ toJson(secrets) }}' | base64)
      env:
        KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD }}
        KEY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}
```